# Accessing a server via script, both running inside the same Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, localhost

I'm trying to run node.js/mocha integration tests inside a Docker container. As part of my integration tests, I start web servers in child processes (e.g. localhost:8000) and then query different urls to see if everything works as expected (e.g. localhost:8000/some/file.json) - everything within the container.

Everything works outside of the Docker container but when I run inside Docker, it seems as if localhost cannot be resolved properly, so that the requests stay within the container.

How do I access a server running inside the same Docker container, if not via localhost?

For example, the following script leads to a 503 error when run inside the Docker container.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
request.debug = true;

var port = 8000;
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server started', port);
  request('http://localhost:'+port+'/package.json', function(err, response) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('status', response.statusCode);
  });
});
```

I already tried several things already like connecting via bash and using curl to check if the server is running. When I expose the port to my host machine, then it seems as if the server is started correctly.

Most topics I've found on SO or Google were about connecting your host machine to Docker, but I didn't find anything about localhost inside Docker.

Any help is much appreciated!

Update:
`/etc/hosts` has the following content:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  44453c0f8f46
```

Comment: Couple of question. Are you sure with the port? In the example you specified 8011 and you use `localhost:8000`. What is the content of your `/ect/hosts` file inside the container?

Comment: I adjusted the port above in the sample script above. In the tests that I ran (automatically with mocha or manually with e.g. curl in cmd), the ports are aligned. Again, test scripts work locally on OSX.
I added the content of `/etc/hosts` above.

Comment: Please show the commands you are running to launch your container, and to then launch your script that runs in the same container.

Comment: As you are getting 503, I am pretty sure that localhost is getting resolved. 503 must be thrown by your service. And are you saying it works fine when you expose the port and hitting the service from host machine?